# Decision Tree in R: rpart on categorical variables

Tags: r, rpart

**Introduction:**

---

I would like to build a classifier which distinguishes between buyers and non-buyers based on user behavior. This data is **highly imbalanced** (0.009% for positive class), and I'm currently trying the `rpart()` from `library(rpart)` to build such a classifier (*I'm also considering Random Forests, please make a comment if I should use it*)

**Dataset**

---

You can use the following code to load the dataframe:

```
df.train <- structure(list(result = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), totals_pageviews = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
15L), totals_sessionQualityDim = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 45L, 16L, 
1L, 1L, 40L), device_deviceCategory = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("desktop", "mobile", 
"tablet"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("result", "pageviews", 
"quality", "device"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is just a sample dataset, I have more dimensions and rows. Other dimensions are categorical with 50+ levels.

Here's the overview of the dataset...
[image: Data Overview]

Instantly, I notice that the result column is just an integer. This should infact be a factor, and I am using `method="class"` in the `rpart()` for this reason.

**Method**

---

Here is my tree where I created a loss matrix, so that False Negatives are given a higher cost:

```
lossmatrix <- matrix(c(0,10,1,0), byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)
mytree <- rpart(result ~.,data = df.train, method = "class",
                maxdepth=4, minsplit = 10, minbucket=5,
                parms = list(loss=lossmatrix))
```

Should I use `as.factor()` on my factor variables? Or does `rpart()` automatically fix them? It seems that R already knows which are factors by the picture above.

Next, I plotted the prediction tree:

```
pred.tree <- predict(mytree, newdata = df.test)
```

Checked the accuracy using:

```
accuracy.meas(df.test$result, pred.tree[,1])
```

*This gave me* precision: 0.009, recall: 1.000, F: **0.009**, which looks like I'm predicting 1 to all situations...

> I'm also not sure which class does `rpart()` take as the positive
>   class, because it could be that the algorithm is predicting 0 all the
>   time (due to imbalance) which gives me good recall (since it correctly
>   finds 'positive' classes) and bad precision, because I always predict
>   0.

Additionaly, in the guide I've followed `accuracy.meas(df.test$result, pred.tree[,1])` is substituted by `accuracy.meas(df.test$result, pred.tree[,2])` and if I exclude the `method="class"` from `rpart()` none of the above work, and I need to simply have `accuracy.meas(df.test$result, pred.tree)`, so I'm not sure about the indexes.

Lastly, I tried undersampling, oversampling, using ROSE() without lossmatrix, all without any improvement. ROC area is consistently over 0.95 for all variations, F score doesn't pass 0.1

**EDIT UNDERSTAMPLING:**

```
#under sampling
data_balanced_under <- ovun.sample(result ~ ., data = df.train, method = "under",N = 50190)$data
table(data_balanced_under$result)
#    0     1 
#25095 25095 

tree.under <- rpart(result ~ ., data = data_balanced_under, method="class")
pred.tree.under <- predict(tree.under, newdata = df.test)

accuracy.meas(df.test$result, pred.tree.under[,2]) #F 0.08, P=0.088, R=0.957
roc.curve(df.test$result, pred.tree.under[,2])
Area under the curve (AUC): 0.935
```

[image: ROC]

Comment: I tried under sampling, 25095 positive class occurrences,  2893855 negative

Comment: If you undersampled (25095 positive, 25095 negative examples) there is no possible way to have an AUC > .95 and an F1 < .1. The math just doesn't work.

Comment: @Zach Please see my edit... I've double checked, everything seems to be fine

Comment: Post the confusion matrix of test results.

Comment: To get the confusion matrix, I've added type="class" to my prediction call. This gave me: table(pred.tree.under)
     0      1 \\
881230  9175 \\ This is the test set, so it's imbalanced

Comment: Maybe it's because df.test$result is not a factor, and pred.tree.under gives back a factor? I don't really know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158619/discussion-between-zach-and-grs).

Comment: `predict(mytree, newdata = df.test)` should return a matrix with column names the classes you want to predict (i.e. 0s and 1s). Have a look and then decide which column to use as predicted values within 'accuracy.meas`